# Lookup values from one Dataframe with another dataframe and then creating a new column in df1 based on if the condition is met

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two data frames.

- df1 has a datetime column and
- df2 has three columns 'start time' and 'end time' alongwith a column called " stage number" .

I am trying to lookup **datetime **value in the **df1 dataframe** to see if it  is between **Start Time** and **end time** columns in **df2** and if that is true then create a new column in df1 with the stage number from the **df2 dataframe**.

I can do that with the iteration function but that is too time consuming for big files.  What are other ways i can do this ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something like `df1.merge(df2, how='cross').query('datetime.between(\`start time\`, \`end time\`')`

Comment: Sample input and expected output would help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I created source DataFrames (*df1* and *df2*) as:

```
             datetime
0 2022-01-03 10:30:00
1 2022-01-03 11:20:00
2 2022-01-05 12:00:00
3 2022-01-05 08:00:00
4 2022-01-06 16:05:00
```

and

```
           start time            end time  stage number
0 2022-01-03 10:00:00 2022-01-03 12:00:00             1
1 2022-01-04 10:00:00 2022-01-04 16:00:00             2
2 2022-01-05 10:00:00 2022-01-06 18:00:00             3
3 2022-01-10 10:00:00 2022-01-20 18:00:00             4
```

*datetime*, *start time* and *end time* columns are of *datetime64[ns]* type.

Note that *2022-01-05 08:00:00* in *df1* is not contained between any
pair of start / end times in *df2*.
In such a case (no stage) the stage number will be set to *0*.

Start with computing 3 auxiliary *Numpy* arrays:

```
st = df2['start time'].values
et = df2['end time'].values
dat = df1.datetime.values[:,None]
```

Then compute the new column as:

```
df1['stage'] = np.dot(np.logical_and(np.less_equal(st, dat),
    np.less_equal(dat, et)), df2['stage number'])
```

The result is:

```
             datetime  stage
0 2022-01-03 10:30:00      1
1 2022-01-03 11:20:00      1
2 2022-01-05 12:00:00      3
3 2022-01-05 08:00:00      0
4 2022-01-06 16:05:00      3
```

Comment: Thank you so much Valdi_Bo , It gives me an error saying 
"NameError: name 'st' is not defined"

Comment: My mistake. Initially I used variables named "s1 and "s2", but finally I decided to use more meaningful names: *st* for start time and *et* for end time. Unfortunately, old names remained in the "initial" section. Now the code is OK.